# Raspberry pi 4b Reconnect USB

Tags: usb

My usb devices work normaly my only problem is when i unplug my usb device and reconnect it i have to reboot my pi to get it to work even though lsusb does show the device i just reconnected.

Is there a way to get the usbs to work again without rebooting the pi?

---

default power supply and doesnt matter what usb device they all do it.
i'm running raspbian os "this is the only os that i'm having this problem with"
I tried ubuntu and manjaro they both work when i unplug and replug a usb.

So its a raspbian os thing.

i use my raspberry with moonlight and virtualhere.
virtualhere loads up my usb devices keyboard mouse ect, And when i dismount them from virtualhere / moonlight they stop working on the pi itself since then it tries to replug them in virtualy and only option i do have at that stage is reboot my raspberry pi 4.

also the dmesg this is when i disconnect my test mouse and reconnect it.

https://pastebin.com/bHdiQUDN

Comment: What power supply are you using? What usb devices?

Comment: Can you start the pi with the device plugged in, unplug it, plug it back in and type dmesg ?
Post the return here plz

Comment: What OS? How are you accessing the USB? What is on the USB? Why do you think it doesn't work?

Comment: For future reference Ryoi if you need to make an edit to a question you can use the edit button at the bottom of the question. The Answers section is strictly for answers only. Since you are new here I suggest you take the [Tour](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/tour) to find out out how the site works.